# Finding maximum of an expression by considering it as a function and using endpoints of interval

Tags: real-analysis

To illustrate my point consider following problem in one of the books I am reading.

> Given a positive integer $a$ find the maximum of
> $\sum_{k=1}^n (a-a_1)(a-a_2)...(a-a_{k-1})a_k(a-a_{k+1})..(a-a_n)$
> Where $a_1,a_2,..a_n$ range independently over the interval  $[0,a]$

**solution given in the book:**

For an index $k$ fix $a_1,..a_{k-1},a_{k+1},...a_n$ and think of given expression as function of $a_k$.This function linear, hence its maximum is on end points of the interval $[0,a]$ (###).Repeating the argument for each variable we conclude that expression reaches maximum for certain choice of $a_k=0$ or $a$,$k=1,2,3....n$.If one $a_k$ is $a$ and others are $ 0$ the expression is equal to $a^n$.Hence this is the desired maximum

All makes sense up to (###) part. Why does repeating this logic to other variables work?Say it works somehow,then consider expression as function in $a_k$ and found that maximum is reached for $a_k=1$.Shouldn't this imply all variables should be $a$ to attain maximum.Why consider some values as $a$ and others as $0$ This is a new concept for me.Can anybody explain the reason??. Thanks for spending your time for me.

Comment: Essentially because there are no local maxima or minima, so these must be at the boundary of $[0,a]^n$.

Comment: @Chrystomath can you provide some links regarding this method?

Answer (score 1):

The function $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \mapsto f(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ you are referring to is continuous on $[0,a]^n$, which is a compact set, and thus it has a maximum. Let $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ be a maximum point of $f$, and suppose there exists $k$ such that $0 < b_k < a$.

$f_k : a_k \mapsto f(b_1, \dots, b_{k-1}, a_k, b_{k+1}, \dots, b_n)$ is a linear function on $[0,a]$ so one of $a_k = 0$ or $a_k = a$ reaches its maximum (or both if this linear function is constant). This means we can set $b_k = 0$ or $b_k = a$ (depending on which reaches the maximum) and still get a maximum of $f$ at $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$.

You can repeat this argument a finite number of time until all $b_k$'s are $0$ or $a$, proving at least one point of $\{0,a\}^n $ reaches the maximum of $f$.

Then you can just try all possible combinations and see that the maximum is indeed the one given in the solution.

Is that clearer?

Comment: can you provide links which is related to the above??